# Why does the output of some Linux programs go to neither STDOUT nor STDERR?

Tags: linux, bash, gnu, stdout, stderr

Why does the output of some Linux programs go to neither STDOUT nor STDERR?

Actually, I want to know how to reliably capture all program output, no matter what 'stream' it uses. The problem I have is that some programs do not seem to let their output be captured.

An example is the 'time' command:

```
time sleep 1 2>&1 > /dev/null

real        0m1.003s
user        0m0.000s
sys         0m0.000s
```

or

```
time sleep 1 &> /dev/null

real        0m1.003s
user        0m0.000s
sys         0m0.000s
```

Why do I see output both times? I expected it all to be piped into [/dev/null](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null).

What output stream is time using, and how can I pipe it into a file?

One way to work around the problem is to create a [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) script, for example, `combine.sh` containing this command:

```
$@ 2>&1
```

Then the output of 'time' can be captured in the correct way:

```
combine.sh time sleep 1 &> /dev/null
```

(no output is seen - correct)

Is there a way to achieve what I want without using a separate combine script?

Comment: first you should reverse the order: `2>&1 > /dev/null` means "2 now goes to where 1 goes (ie, the terminal, by default), and then 1 now goes to /dev/null (but 2 still goes to the terminal!). use `>/dev/null 2>&1` to say "1 goes now to /dev/null, then 2 goes to where 1 goes (ie, also to /dev/null) . This still won't work here as the builtin 'time' won't get redirected, but is more generally correct (for example it would work if you use /usr/bin/time). Think about "2>&1" as copying 1's "direction" into 2, not as 2 going to 1

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This question is addressed in [BashFAQ/032](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032). In your example, you would:

```
{ time sleep 1; } 2> /dev/null
```

The reason why

```
time sleep 1 2>/dev/null
```

doesn't behave how you're expecting is because with that syntax, you'll want to `time` the command `sleep 1 2>/dev/null` (yes, the command `sleep 1` with *stderr* redirected to `/dev/null`). The builtin `time` works that way so as to make this actually possible.

The `bash` *builtin* can actually do this because... well, it's a builtin. Such a behavior would be impossible with the external command `time` usually located in `/usr/bin`. Indeed:

```
$ /usr/bin/time sleep 1 2>/dev/null
$
```

Now, the answer to your question

> Why does the output of some linux programs go to neither STDOUT nor STDERR?

is: it does, the output goes to *stdout* or *stderr*.

Hope this helps!

Comment: you can create other fd and have commands explicitely go to those (ex: in bash script:  `exec 3>/some/file ; ls >&3 ;` )

Comment: @OlivierDulac Sure, or even simpler with the `coproc` builtin. But it's not the case for the `time` builtin.

Comment: @gniourf-gniourf: I was commenting because of your sentence "the output goes to stdout or stderr" ^^

Answer (score 16):

Your particular question about `time` builtin has been answered, but there *are* some commands that don't write either to `stdout` or to `stderr`.  A classic example is the Unix command [`crypt`](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/crypt.c).  `crypt` with no arguments encrypts standard input `stdin` and writes it to standard output `stdout`.  It prompts the user for a password using [`getpass()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/getpass.html), which by default outputs a prompt to `/dev/tty`.  `/dev/tty` is the current terminal device.  Writing to `/dev/tty` has the effect of writing to the current terminal (if there is one, see `isatty()`).

The reason `crypt` can't write to `stdout` is because it writes encrypted output to `stdout`.  Also, it's better to prompt to `/dev/tty` instead of writing to `stderr` so that if a user redirects `stdout` and `stderr`, the prompt is still seen.  (For the same reason, `crypt` can't read the password from `stdin`, since it's being used to read the data to encrypt.)

Comment: +1. Less relevant for the OP, but more relevant for everyone coming across "Why does the output of some linux programs go to neither STDOUT nor STDERR?" via Google. :-)

Comment: Yes, I too came here via Google looking for this. Specifically `xattr` on macOS writes failures, such as `xattr: No such file: /Volumes/blah-blah-volume/blah-blah-file` to neither stdout nor stderr. I have to re-run a very, very long-running xattr job because I'd run it in screen, piping stdout and stderr to respective files, only to find out both were empty and all failure messages lost except for the last few handfuls still in the screen's buffer. Is there a way to pipe `/dev/tty` to a file to capture this output?

Comment: @DanielSmedegaardBuus you might be able to use `script` command (e.g., see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/647847/31226)

Answer (score 0):

`time sleep 1 > /dev/null 2>&1` # redirects "sleep's" output do null. Then, "time" writes its own output, with no redirection. It is like "`time (sleep 1 > /dev/null 2>&1)`".

`(time sleep 1) > /dev/null 2>&1` # runs "time sleep 1", then redirects its output to null.

[]s

Answer (score -1):

The problem in your case is that the redirection works in another way. You wrote

```
time sleep 1 2>&1 > /dev/null
```

This redirects the standard output to `/dev/null` and then redirects the standard error to standard output.

To redirect all output you have to write

```
time sleep 1 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Then the standard error will be redirected to the standard output and after that all the standard output (containing the standard error) will be redirected to `/dev/null`.

Comment: This doesn't work with the bash _builtin_ `time`. See my answer for some explanations.

Comment: +1 because this is a useful answer to a similar question. Although @Olivier explains it better in the comment to the question above.